# pyQt equivalent of asyncore/asynchat

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt

Is there an equivalent of asyncore/asynchat in pyQt ?

If not, then i trust there wouldn't be a problem by just using asyncore/asynchat in a client-server GUI application, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, QTcpSocket/QTcpServer in QNetwork module can work asynchronously, like most of QNetwork's classes.

From documentation at http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/network-programming.html:

> QTcpSocket works asynchronously and emits signals to report status
>   changes and errors, just like QNetworkAccessManager and QFtp.

Comment: Thanks, i will read some examples of QNetworkAccessManager which looks more generic.

Comment: by the way, what is the difference between asyncore and asynchat ?

Comment: Qt doesn't support Udp Multicast yet! So i will have to go with asyncore/asynchat.